# Does TimeZone.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId need to be localized?

Tags: datetime, localization, timezone

Given the following example:

```
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "Atlantic Standard Time");
```

Since `Atlantic Standard Time` is a string, is this safe? AKA, if I were to run the same code on a German OS, would the code fail? If so, how should I properly handle timezones like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone identifiers, such as obtained by the `Id` property of a `TimeZoneInfo` object, are not localized.  They match to the registry key name found at:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
```

They are always in English, and should not be translated.  So yes, it is safe.

On the other hand, the `DisplayName`, `StandardName` and `DaylightName` properties *are* localized.  They use the localization of the operating system itself, ignoring any changes you may have made to the `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` in your application.